# Single sign-on with Chef

Tags: reverse-proxy, openid, chef

I'm getting my personal infrastructure set up (Gitlab, Jenkins, etc.) and I'm planning on using OpenID for single sign-on. I understand that SSO works for Gitlab and Jenkins.

Would I be able to configure Chef the same way? If not, would it be possible to do it by some other means (e.g. Chef behind Apache reverse proxy that handles auth)?

Comment: Are you referring just to chef's web interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Chef Server WebUI can use OpenID. It's documented in [Chef Configuration Settings](https://wiki.opscode.com/display/ChefCN/Chef+Configuration+Settings).